# How delete functions on python?

Tags: python, function, timestamp, crc32

I have one game server. I have one tools and i used this for generate crc32  + timestamp and save to file.. but this script file have more functions and I don't want use them.I need just Get crc32, timestamp and save to file.

I try to delete these functions but not work it give syntax or another error. I tried 100x.. And I want post here, maybe someone can help me..

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

from urllib import urlopen
from datetime import date
import sys
import os
import zlib
import getopt
import csv
import zipfile

#
# Utility functions
#

def FindFilesByExt(path, ext):
    ext = ext.lower()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if name[-len(ext):].lower() == ext:
                yield os.path.join(root, name)

def GetFileCrc32(filename):
    crc = 0
    for line in open(filename, "rb"):
        crc = zlib.crc32(line, crc)

    return "%x" % (crc & 0xffffffff)

def FormatName(filename):
    if filename[:2] == ".\\":
        filename = filename[2:]

    return filename.replace("\\", "/")

def GetLastModifiedTime(filename):
    # http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167296
    # How To Convert a UNIX time_t to a Win32 FILETIME or SYSTEMTIME
    EPOCH_AS_FILETIME = 116444736000000000  # January 1, 1970 as MS file time
    HUNDREDS_OF_NANOSECONDS = 10000000

    return EPOCH_AS_FILETIME + long(os.path.getmtime(filename)) * HUNDREDS_OF_NANOSECONDS

#
# Real code
#

class Patch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.patch_url = None

        # Patch file list
        self.file_dict = dict()
        self.file_list = None

    def SetName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def SetPatchUrl(self, url):
        self.patch_url = url

    def AddFilesFromPatchUrl(self):
        for line in urlopen(self.patch_url):
            line = line.split()
            print line
            line[4] = FormatName(line[4])
            self.file_dict[line[4].lower()] = line

    def AddFile(self, filename):
        filename = FormatName(filename)
        mtime = GetLastModifiedTime(filename)

        #
        # Format is as following:
        # unpacked_crc unpacked_size low_last_edit high_last_edit path
        #

        self.file_dict[filename.lower()] = [GetFileCrc32(filename),
                            "%d" % (os.path.getsize(filename)),
                            "%d" % (mtime >> 32),
                            "%d" % (mtime & 0xffffffff), filename]

        # Sorted list no longer contains all files. Invalidate it.
        self.file_list = None

    def GetCrcList(self):
        self.__SortFileList()

        output = ""
        for entry in self.file_list:
            output += (" ".join(entry) + "\n")

        return output

    def __SortFileList(self):
        if not self.file_list:
            self.file_list = [self.file_dict[key] for key in self.file_dict]
            self.file_list.sort(key=lambda entry: entry[4].lower()) # 4 = filename index


kPatchConfigFieldNames = ["Name", "Url"]

def GetPatchInstance(filename, desiredName):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=kPatchConfigFieldNames, dialect='excel-tab')
        reader.next()

        for row in reader:
            if row["Name"] == desiredName:
                patch = Patch()
                patch.SetName(row["Name"])
                patch.SetPatchUrl(row["Url"])
                return patch

    raise RuntimeError("Failed to find %s!" % (desiredName))
    return None

def WriteXmlFile(filename, files):
    file = open(filename, "wb+")

    file.write('<ScriptFile>')

    for f in files:
        file.write('\t<CreateLz Input="%s" Output="%s.lz" />\n' % (f, f))

    file.write('</ScriptFile>')

def main(argv):
    #
    # Parse command-line arguments
    #

    optlist, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], 'a:f:p:', ['archive=', 'file=', 'patchcfg='])

    archives = list()
    files = list()
    patchConfigName = None

    for name, value in optlist:
        if name == "--archive" or name == "-a":
            files.append("pack/" + value + ".eix")
            files.append("pack/" + value + ".epk")
        elif name == "--file" or name == "-f":
            files.append(value)
        elif name == "--patchcfg" or name == "-p":
            patchConfigName = value

    #
    # Decide over patch-config to use...
    #

    patch = GetPatchInstance("PatchConfig.txt", patchConfigName)

    # Add already existing files
    patch.AddFilesFromPatchUrl()

    # Process files
    WriteXmlFile("make_patch.xml", files)

    os.system("FileArchiver make_patch.xml")

    os.unlink("make_patch.xml")

    # Create patch ZIP
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile("PATCH_%s_%s.zip" % (patchConfigName, date.today().strftime("%m%d%Y")), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for file in files:
        patch.AddFile(file)
        file = file + ".lz"
        zip.write(file)
        os.unlink(file)

    zip.writestr("crclist", patch.GetCrcList())

    zip.close()

main(sys.argv)
```

If you want to try out this script, run this in the cmd:

```
python make_patch.py -f filename.extension -p patch_live
```

For this to run, it needs `PatchConfig.txt` in same folder

[make_patch.py](http://pastebin.com/6MFpAWZ9)

[PatchConfig.txt](http://pastebin.com/F1ZRWFZE)

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you've tried?

Comment: @Louis Thank you for your interest, its possible to disable other functions? just need get crc32+timestamp and save it "crclist" file.

I tried delete functions but i can't success, i still trying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete functions from a script, you need to make sure that the function you deleted is *not* being called later in the code.

For example, let's say your script looks like this:

```
def foo(x):
    return x*x

def banana():
    return "Peel"

def bar():
    return "My " + banana()

i = int(raw_input("Please enter a number to be squared: "))

print foo(i) #prints the number you entered, squared

print banana() #prints "Peel"

print bar() #prints "My Peel"
```

So, if I only want the functionality of the functions `bar()` and `foo(x)` and I don't need to use the function`banana()`, I can delete these functions.  However, if I *only* delete the function `banana()`, it will give an error, like so:

```
def foo(x):
    return x*x

#deleted banana()

def bar():
    return "My " + banana()

i = int(raw_input("Please enter a number to be squared: "))

print foo(i) #prints the number you entered, squared

print banana() #gives an error because banana() is not defined

print bar() #not executed because of the above error.
```

Let's delete `print banana()` and see if that fixes it.

```
def foo(x):
    return x*x

#deleted banana()

def bar():
    return "My " + banana()

i = int(raw_input("Please enter a number to be squared: "))

print foo(i) #prints the number you entered, squared

#deleted print banana()

print bar() #error because the bar() function calls the deleted banana() function
```

This still does not work, because the `bar()` function calls `banana()` here:

```
def bar():
    return "My " + banana()
```

When you delete a function, you need to delete *every single call to that function*, no matter where it is.  If not, Python will try to call a function that doesn't exist and will give you an error.  The correct example code for removing all traces of `banana()` is below:

```
def foo(x):
    return x*x

#deleted banana()

def bar():
    return "My " + "Peel" # removed banana()

i = int(raw_input("Please enter a number to be squared: "))

print foo(i) #prints the number you entered, squared

#deleted print banana()

print bar() #prints "My Peel"
```

When you apply this to your code, make sure no functions you delete are called directly by any function you want to save (the crc32 function).  In my example, if you wanted to keep the `bar()` function, the `banana()` function is actually necessary to run `bar()` so you should not delete it.

In your code, the `AddFile` method is what you call when you call `GetFileCrc32()`.  As you can see, `FormatName()` and `GetLastModifiedTime()` are both called as well.  These functions are necessary for `GetFileCrc32()` to work so you should *not* delete them.

```
 def AddFile(self, filename):
    filename = FormatName(filename)
    mtime = GetLastModifiedTime(filename)

    #
    # Format is as following:
    # unpacked_crc unpacked_size low_last_edit high_last_edit path
    #

    self.file_dict[filename.lower()] = [GetFileCrc32(filename),
                        "%d" % (os.path.getsize(filename)),
                        "%d" % (mtime >> 32),
                        "%d" % (mtime & 0xffffffff), filename]

    # Sorted list no longer contains all files. Invalidate it.
    self.file_list = None
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks you give me something ! I tryed to write "crclist" file not in zip, but it give error :

`F:\Metin2ServerFiles\Clients\Client_Work\Metin2Galactica-Released>python make_pa
tch.py -f Metin2.exe -p patch_live
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "make_patch.py", line 179, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "make_patch.py", line 175, in main
    file.writestr("crclist", patch.GetCrcList())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'writestr'`

Comment: Thanks for helping me ^^ I found one way.. I disable zipping full files, just zip **"crclist"** file :)


`zip = zipfile.ZipFile("PATCH_%s_%s.zip" % (patchConfigName, date.today().strftime("%m%d%Y")), "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
 
 for file in files:
  patch.AddFile(file)
  # file = file + ".lz"
  # zip.write(file)
  # os.unlink(file)
  zip.writestr("crclist", patch.GetCrcList())
  zip.close()`

Comment: try using file.write() instead, that may help?

Comment: Did you get it??  Awesome!